# Do I need to free structs within structs?

Tags: c, struct

I have the following piece of code. I want to properly free all my memory. As you can see, I have a b_struct within an a_struct. I wonder whether I need to manually free the b_struct within the a_struct, and if so, what is the proper way to do it?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct b_struct {
    int c;
};

struct a_struct {
    struct b_struct b;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  struct a_struct *a;
  a = calloc(1, sizeof(*a));
  a->b.c = 5;
  printf("Value: %d", a->b.c);
  free(a);
}
```

Comment: No, you do not, unless the `b` member is itself a pointer allocated through `malloc`.

Comment: You never malloced `b` so you can't free it.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I don’t think `realloc`  should be in that list; the number of memory blocks which need to be freed doesn’t change when you call that. I’d also note that sometimes library functions allocate or free memory for you so if you only count code you see that heuristic might be off.

Comment: Rule of thumb: you need to free only what has been allocated via `malloc` and friends.

Comment: @DanielH Agreed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I wonder whether I need to manually free the b_struct within the a_struct

No.

From the [`malloc(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/free.3.html) man page:

> The `free()` function frees the memory space pointed to by `ptr`, which must have been returned by a previous call to `malloc()`, `calloc()`, or `realloc()`.

When you allocated `sizeof(struct a_struct)` bytes, that includes all members of that structure, including the `struct b_struct` member. This struct member is no different than an `int` or `char[]` member; it's all just one contiguous block of memory to the allocator.

Answer (score 2):

No. Not only do you not *need* to, you are not *allowed* to. The memory used in `b` is a part of the memory used in `a`; you need to free the latter as a single unit, and that includes all of the memory for `b`.

In general, your program should call `free` exactly once for each call to `malloc` or `calloc`. This doesn’t mean the number of lines of code calling `free` needs to be the same as the number of lines calling allocation functions; it means that each time you run the program, each call to `free` should be paired with exactly one call to an allocation function, and vice versa, with limited exceptions:

- If the allocation fails (and returns `NULL`), you don’t need to call `free` on `NULL`.
- You can call `free` on `NULL` as many times as you want, although you usually don’t want.
- You might call library functions which then allocate or free memory internally. This isn’t really an exception; each of those functions must still be matched with a corresponding free or allocation (respectively), but if you just look at `malloc`, `calloc`, and `free` you might miss something.
- When your earliest opportunity to free a chunk of memory is right before the program exits, you don’t need to bother, because the OS reclaims all the memory atthat point anyway. This point in particular has its own caveats, but they are at best tangential to this issue.

If you fail to `free` memory which was allocated, you have a memory leak. Your program will use more and more memory until the OS can’t give it any more, at which point it will probably crash.

If you `free` memory which was not allocated by one of the standard allocation functions, or `free` the same memory twice, it gets even worse: this is immediately undefined behavior (UB) and might do anything*. This is the type of bug you would introduce by trying to free `b`; the memory in question was not the actual pointer returned by `calloc`, and even if it were it would have already been freed as part of `a`.

---

* People often say UB might do anything a lot, but in practice you can often predict what will happen on a real system; it won’t make your computer explode unless you actually have a USB bomb plugged into the computer in question. However, I would classify invalid frees as one of the less-tame types of UB: the errors it introduces can in practice appear later than the actual bug, cause seemingly unrelated issues, and be unstable between multiple runs of the program (meaning things might look fine when you test but fail when you try to use the program, and be hard to debug). With many other forms of UB this is allowed but not as likely in practice to happen.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, no.

You would only need to manually free the inner struct if it was allocated separately from the outer struct.  Example:

```
struct a_struct 
{
  struct b_struct *b;
};

int main( void )
{
  struct a_struct *a = malloc( sizeof *a );
  if ( a ) // *Always* check the result of malloc or calloc
  {
    a->b = malloc( sizeof *a->b );
    if ( a->b )
    {
      // do stuff with a->b->c
      free( a->b );  // free in reverse order that you allocated
    }
    free( a );
  }
  return 0;
}
```

You should only `free` pointer values returned from `malloc`, `calloc`, or `realloc`.